# soundcloud API /track query filtering

Tags: soundcloud

From: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/tracks#filtering

I'm not sure from the docs if this functionality is available.  I want to be able to:

use a range filter for comment_count, download_count, playback_count, favoritings_count, e.g. favoritings_count[from]=100

Is there a way I can use a range filter on # of favoritings with the current API?

I also see there are filters for "genres" and "types", but no examples are given.  How do I use these filters?

Comment: You should accept @PaulOsman's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tracks resource does not currently support filtering on any of the properties you mentioned. You can apply interval filters to bpm, duration and created_at. You can however, set the 'order' param to 'hotness'. A tracks 'hotness' is determined by a number of factors, including the number of favoritings.

Genre is a user defined field, and therefore there isn't a strict enumeration of valid values. Common ones are things like 'dubstep' or 'house' or 'punk', etc. Types is currently one of: other, sample, sound effect, loop, stem, in progress, demo, podcast, spoken, recording, live, remix, original. Note that these are subject to change in the future.

I'll look into adding a list of valid values for 'types' to the docs. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The `hotness` order is a nice one! But is there somewhere in the docs where all admitted values for ordering are defined?

Comment: Hotness is now deprecated :( https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/removing-hotness-param